# Unable to refresh plt.axhline() in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation, livegraph

I'm just trying to make a live graph using matplotlib.However I couldn't find a way to draw-remove-redraw axhline(). My aim is to show a horizontal line of newest value of Y axis values and of course remove the recent horizontal line.

`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import time
from random import randrange

style.use("fivethirtyeight")

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
#ax1 = plt.subplot()
second = 1

xs = list()
ys = list()
ann_list = []
a = 0
ten = 10


def animate(i):
    global second
    global a, ten

    random = randrange(ten)
    ys.append(random)
    xs.append(second)
    second += 1

    ax1.plot(xs, ys, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b')



    plt.axhline(y = ys[-1], linewidth=2, color='r', linestyle='-')
    if len(xs) > 2:
        plt.axhline(y = ys[-2], linewidth=2, color='r', linestyle='-').remove()



    if len(ys) > 20 and len(xs) > 20:
        ax1.lines.pop(0)
        ys.pop(0)
        xs.pop(0)
        a += 1

    ax1.set_xlim(a, (21 + a))
    # ax1.set_ylim(0, 200)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

`

expecting that to only show the newest y axis values with a horizontal line. However horizontal lines doesn't vanish away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, this:

```
plt.axhline(y = ys[-2], linewidth=2, color='r', linestyle='-').remove()
```

doesn't remove the previous `axhline`; it adds a new `axhline` at `y=ys[-2]` and then immediately removes it. So, it effectively does nothing.

You have to remove the same line you inserted with `plt.axhline`. Save the object returned by this function somewhere, and remove it when the next frame is animated.

Here's a solution with a bit of default mutable argument abuse.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import time
from random import randrange

style.use("fivethirtyeight")

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
second = 1

xs = list()
ys = list()
ann_list = []
a = 0
ten = 10

def animate(i, prev_axhline=[]):
    global second
    global a, ten

    random = randrange(ten)
    ys.append(random)
    xs.append(second)
    second += 1

    ax1.plot(xs, ys, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b')



    if prev_axhline:
        prev_axhline.pop().remove()
    prev_axhline.append(plt.axhline(y = ys[-1], linewidth=2, color='r', linestyle='-'))



    if len(ys) > 20 and len(xs) > 20:
        ax1.lines.pop(0)
        ys.pop(0)
        xs.pop(0)
        a += 1

    ax1.set_xlim(a, (21 + a))
    # ax1.set_ylim(0, 200)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

Comment: works flawlessly! Thank you very much. I will do a sensor project and this answer is very helpful for me